# Why the element is calling the function with its old index and not with the updated index?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

In my code I am doing something which is similar to this,

```dart
List widgetList = List.generate(
  3,
  (index) => Container(
    color: getColor(index),
  ),
);

// Now updating the element of List.

temp = widgetList.removeLast();
widgetList.insertAt(0, temp);

// Now after the update, the widget which is now at index 0 is still calling
// getColor() function with its old index 3 i.e. the index with which it was created.
```

How can I solve this problem? In my code I have to change the order of stackChildernList to get my desired animation.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is absolutely normal , think about it , when usint the constructor `List.generate` you are passing a function that generates it immediately ! adding or removeing or altering an element in the list won't be happening using the old function passed in the constructor !!

if this wasn't the behavior before you upgrade the sdk then it should be a glitch in the old version .